# ref is null in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I have a ref to a KonvaJS stage. In ComponentDidMount, the value of this.stageRef.current is null. Any ideas why?

My code looks as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Text } from 'react-konva';
import Konva from 'konva';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.stageRef = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.stageRef.current is null here!
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <>
          <Stage id="canvas-text"
            width={400} height={163}
            className="stage"
            ref={this.stageRef}>
            <Layer>
              <Text fontFamily='Karla' fontSize={24} align='center' width={400} y={30} text={"Hello"} />
            </Layer>
          </Stage>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stage` component is a function component that forward the reference to its underlying child. [You can inspect the sources](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/blob/b08ac251f026881595f619e162f71db36dca1ec1/src/ReactKonvaCore.js#L116):

```js
export const Stage = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <StageWrap {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />;
});
```

A straight example as the one you provided shows that [the `ref` references the underlying `StageWrap` component appropriately](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-frog-0l63h).

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: It explains how this should be working and adds with a live working example.

Comment: I'm not quite following. The code you've put in that Codesandbox seems to be exactly the same as OP's (formatting notwithstanding).

Comment: @tmarwen is right. For the question I (over) simplified my code and unintentionally removed my own bug!